# Do carrots need to be within a certain range of the player to grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Question is pretty simple, i'm trying to make a villager-powered carrot farm in spawn chunks, but I want to know if carrots are like saplings and grass and need to be within a certain range of a player in order to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the chunk needs to be loaded, but their growth also depends on "random ticks", which only happen in a roughly 128 block radius around the player. The exact definition from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick#Chunk_tick) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Tick&oldid=1354882#Chunk_tick)):

> On every game tick, each chunk within the render distance of a player and with centers within 128 blocks of a player are ticked.

Comment: so essentially within the same range that mobs can spawn, is the range which you need to be for carrots to grow?

Comment: Almost. Mobs spawn exactly in the 128 block range, while block ticks happen if the center of a chunk section is in a 128 block range. So it's a more jagged edge, the closest points of it can be ~114 blocks away from you, the furthest can be ~142 blocks away from you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

The long and short of it is that plants grow (as well as other processes, such as smelting, or animals growing, etc.) in [loaded Chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Loaded_and_unloaded_chunks). Normally, a player does need to be in range of a Chunk for it to be loaded. If they plants are in the loaded Chunk, they will grow. If they are not in a loaded Chunk, they won't grow.

However, there are some exceptions to this. [Spawn Chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk#Spawn_chunks) are permanently loaded. Any and all activity will continue in these Chunks, regardless of whether or not the player is in range.

Additionally, you can create [Chunk loaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeq5GZxRH9s) that can keep Chunks loaded, in a similar fashion to the spawn chunks, but the downside is that this is a little complicated, and can create a heavy load on your PC.